# Android get data usage

Tags: android

I'm modifying the android settings app and I would like to get the data usage, I found this string in the xml file for the datausagesettings but I'm not sure how to access it via java code, the string that is used in the xml is: `android:text="@*android:string/megabyteShort"

Does anyone know how I can access this via java code, I tried R.string.megabyteShort but it doesn't seem to work because it isn't resolved...

Can anyone help me with this?
`

Answer (score 0):

Inside an activity:

`getString(R.string.megabyteShort);`

Inside a fragment:

`getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.megabyteShort);`